# How to display display html(not parsed) in angular2 template

Tags: angular

I am trying to create some sort a sitemap for my app. 
Since I can't use a sitemap generator.

I want to be able to display something like this:

```
  <url>
    <loc>
    http://www.fff.com
    </loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>
    http://www.fff.com/blog/23442
    </loc>
  </url>
```

That way I can copy and past in a xml file.
I tried something like this:

```
<code ngNonBindable>
  <url>
    <loc>
      http://www.fff.com/blog/23442
    </loc>
  </url>
</code>
```

This will only display: `http://www.fff.com/blog/23442`.

Anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: What is the problem? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: is is possible to display with the <url> and <locl> tags surrounding..?

Comment: Doesn't look like an Angular issue. It's added just fine to the DOM, just the browser doesn't show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `html` will get parsed to elements. You have to replace all the `<`and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively:

```
<code>
  &lt;url&gt;
    &lt;loc&gt;
    http://www.fff.com
    &lt;/loc&gt;
  &lt;/url&gt;
  &lt;url&gt;
    &lt;loc&gt;
    http://www.fff.com/blog/23442
    &lt;/loc&gt;
  &lt;/url&gt;
</code>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<pre>
  {{content}}
</pre>
```

```
  content = `<url>
    <loc>
      http://www.fff.com/blog/23442
    </loc>
  </url>`;
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CYHri9pa1IWrvWkBIQBs?p=preview)

Comment: Much better indeed. This should be the accepted answer, considering it's angular :)

Comment: Don't worry. If he prefers your approach, then yours should be accepted. I think the downvote is a bit harsh (upvoted).